# Mixing memory ordering memory_order_seq_cst and memory_order_relaxed in a SPMC queue?

Tags: c, atomic, memory-barriers, lock-free, stdatomic

I'm implementing a chunk-oriented shared ring-buffer for single producer, multiple consumers.

The buffer keeps track of the current iteration (i.e. wrap count) and the last written chunk index.
When writing, the producer first marks the chunk's iteration field as dirty, fills in the other fields (offset/size/etc), then marks the iteration field as non-dirty, with the the same iteration number of the whole buffer. After that, it increments the last written chunk index appropriately.
When reading, the consumers would read the chunk descriptor, verify the iteration is the expected one and it's not being written to, read the data, and verify again.

```
struct chunk_descriptor_t {
  atomic_uint_fast32_t iteration;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t chunk_offset;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t chunk_size;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t user_data;
};

struct shared_buf_descriptor_t {
  atomic_uint_fast32_t total_data_size;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t num_chunks;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t iteration;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t last_written_chunk_idx;
  struct chunk_descriptor_t chunks_descriptors[];
};

typedef enum e_iter_flags {
  ITER_VALUE_MASK = (1 << 30) - 1,
  ITER_PRODUCER_DIRTY = 1 << 30,
  ITER_PRODUCER_RUNNING = 1 << 31
} iter_flags_t;
```

The producer would write the next chunk like this:

```
static void add_chunk(shared_buf_producer_t producer, const char *data,
                      uint32_t chunk_size, uint32_t user_data) {
  uint_fast32_t chunk_idx = (producer->last_written_chunk_idx + 1) %
                            producer->shbuf->header.num_chunks;
  struct chunk_descriptor_t *chunk =
      &producer->shbuf->descriptor->chunks_descriptors[chunk_idx];
  // 1. mark the chunk dirty. This must happen first.
  chunk->iteration =
      ITER_PRODUCER_DIRTY | (producer->iteration & ITER_VALUE_MASK);
  
  // 2. update the chunk fields and write data. This must happen after 1 and before 3.
  // The order inside doesn't matter.
  chunk->chunk_size = chunk_size;
  chunk->user_data = user_data;
  chunk->chunk_offset = producer->write_offset;
  memcpy(producer->shbuf->header.data + producer->write_offset, data,
         chunk_size);
  
  // 3. mark the chunk clean. This must happen after 2 and before 4. 
  chunk->iteration = producer->iteration & ITER_VALUE_MASK;
  
  // 4. update the last written index. This must happen last.
  producer->shbuf->descriptor->last_written_chunk_idx = chunk_idx;
  
  // producer bookkeeping
  producer->write_offset += chunk_size;
  producer->last_written_chunk_idx = chunk_idx;
}
```

So I need to ensure the memory ordering. Currently, `memory_order_seq_cst` is used for all stores. However, this would also order the stores in (2), where the order inside isn't important, as long as (2) as a whole comes after (1) and before (3).

I wonder if I can relax the ordering in (2). And if so, should those be `memory_order_relaxed` stores, or other fields should not be `atomic` at all maybe?

Comment: FYI, `uint_fast32_t` is 64-bit for no good reason on x86-64 glibc.  32-bit integers are the *most* natural size for x86-64, so it's just going to waste space in structs for no actual speed benefit.  Libraries making poor choices unfortunately make `uint_fast32_t` a lot less useful than it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using `[atomic_]uint_fast32t`, so I can test on x86_64, but the code is intended to run on ARM, where it's 32-bit.

Comment: I'd recommend just using `[atomic_]uint32_t`; that's a large enough and fast on all real-world machines.  And better, has the *same* layout as on your ARM systems.  If you explicitly want to allow *huge* queues on 64-bit ISAs, use `size_t`.

Comment: At least on my GCC 12, atomic_uint32_t is not defined, and not sure what the reason for this is. I can only see atomic_uint_fast32_t and atomic_uint_least32_t. I'll read some more to figure it out if I can just add my own `typedef _Atomic uint32_t atomic_uint32_t`;

Comment: Oh weird.  Yeah, you can just use `_Atomic uint32_t` for sure.  Or in this case, `_Atomic unsigned` is also fine in practice on the platforms you care about; it's highly unlikely that some new C implementation will have 16-bit `unsigned` on a "large" system where you wish array indices and sequence counters were at least 32-bit.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the producer attempts to add a chunk to a full queue; or a reader attempts to read from an empty queue? Does it waste potentially massive amounts of CPU time in busy loops?

Comment: @Brendan, the indended use case is for this to be used as audio and video bus. So the producer is non-blocking, will just overwrite. 
The consumers might get notified via side-channel when frame is written, or just sleep for 1/fps secsonds until next frame is available.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommand using [mpmc-queue](https://github.com/rigtorp/MPMCQueue) cause your question is really difficult to answer without writing a book and even if you get one you may discover months if not years later it's culpits.
Lockfree is hard, if you're developer like me and never spent 1 month debugging a simple lf linked list on a 40 core machine you cannot imagine.

From the begining :

```
struct chunk_descriptor_t {
  atomic_uint_fast32_t iteration;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t chunk_offset;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t chunk_size;
  atomic_uint_fast32_t user_data;
};
```

That's OK to declare fields atomic but it's only the begining cause here you introduce false sharing due to cache line granularity. if you have at least 2 core accessing the same data they'll be serialized by L3 cache on x86 then you'll lose any benefits going multicore.

Second, the entire `struct chunk_descriptor_t` is atomic, not just one particular field, it should be protected by a mutex whenever you change something within that field for sake of temporal coherency that means assigning like that is fundamentally wrong cause this 3 lines should be atomic all together:

```
chunk->chunk_size = chunk_size;
chunk->user_data  = user_data;
chunk->chunk_offset = producer->write_offset;
```

On x86 the trick is that every memory access are done implicitly in order giving you a false security feeling, sadly it always turn out to be wrong on platform like ARM.

So the aswer is no you cannot relax anything provided that you read/write field in the same order everywhere in your program, but that's really a non issue since this way of doing lockfree is wrong fundamentally.

Comment: If x86 ordering was enough to produce correctness, you could make that ordering explicit in the source by using `atomic_store_explicit()` with `memory_order_release`.  Then x86 could just use plain stores, ARMv8 32-bit mode could use `stl`.  (ARMv7 would need a barrier before each `str`.)  So which is it?  Do those 3 assignments just need to be ordered (like they are here with default `seq_cst`), or do they need to be a single atomic transaction?

Comment: (On the whole I'd agree with your recommendation to use an existing queue library with a well-tuned and well-tested correct implementation.  But if you are going to say anything about this code, what you're saying seems inconsistent.  You don't always need multiple writes to group together into an atomic transaction.)

Comment: On x86 you have hardware barriers, that does not prevent compilers from reordering that's why atomic is still important.

Comment: Yes of course you have to use `_Atomic`.  All members of the OPs `struct`s *are* `_Atomic`.  (The `memcpy` is non-atomic, though, but the code comments say it order doesn't matter for those 3 stores, only that they happen between 1 and 3.  The `memcpy` is suspicious, but might work in practice with the next store being release or seq_cst)

Comment: @ Peter Cordes The only thing you can do (when using x86) can only write 8 bytes atomically ( maybe 16/32 using sse4 ), anything above requires proper mutex or emulation, 'chunk_descriptor_t' is already 64 bytes

Comment: @Gold, The idea is that `struct chunk_descriptor_t` doesn't need to be atomic. 
I'd check if `chunk_descriptor_t::iteration` is valid, read the others, then check again. That's why I need strong memory ordering guarantees - that marking `iteration` dirty happens first, writing the others happens next, and marking it clean again happens last.

Comment: If you don't think ordering between members is useful, and only 64-byte atomicity is sufficient, why does your answer mention x86's naturally strong ordering?  Also, `chunk_descriptor_t` is 32 bytes, and should be 16 with types that are actually only 32-bit.  (Fun fact: Intel CPUs with AVX *do* guarantee 16-byte atomicity for aligned SSE 16-byte load/store.  But AMD hasn't on-paper guaranteed that yet, even though it's probably also true there.  But that's pretty new for Intel; prior to that you could only get 16-byte atomicity with `lock cmpxchg16b`.  And ARM32 can't do that.)

Comment: My point is that this code is fundamentally wrong, I won't start debating every corner cases, of course you're right about ordering but the algorithm presented here is nowhere near a functioning one ! Take a look at the provided link and try TryEmplace : everything related to atomicity is done well before writing anything into the queue as a reservation then the actual writing takes place as a move operation. Also Folly have an implementation too, you should have a look.

Comment: @Gold, I don't understand what is fundamentally wrong about it. I agree that the code presented isn't complete, but that doesn't invalidate the core of the question, which would be how to achieve total memory order for some stores, yet others to have relaxed ordering between them. Saying "Use something different" does not answer that question.

Comment: @Svetoslav Ilkov Enchev what's fundamentally wrong is that in lockfree programming you always manipulate low level algorithms like Lamport [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_distributed_mutual_exclusion_algorithm] working mostly on atomic adjacent words or double words that have actual atomicity granted. To prevent this structure from leaking we need to access  iteration + chunk_offset +  chunk_size + user_data in every possible ways to support every resize/remap operation. You can see you run into discontinuities that ruin your algorithm. Also having spent some time on LF trees..

Answer (score 0):

After furhter research, I believe the correct implementation should look like this:

```
struct chunk_descriptor_t {
  atomic_uint_fast32_t iteration;
  uint_fast32_t offset;
  uint_fast32_t size;
  uint_fast32_t user_data;
};
```

```
void put_chunk(shared_buf_producer_t producer, uint_fast32_t iteration,
               uint_fast32_t chunk_idx, uint_fast32_t chunk_size,
               uint_fast32_t user_data, const char *data) {
  struct chunk_descriptor_t *chunk =
      &producer->shbuf->descriptor->chunks_descriptors[chunk_idx];
  uint_fast32_t chunk_offset = producer->write_offset;
  // 1. Mark the chunk dirty. This happens first. All previous stores would
  // "happen before" this one.
  atomic_store_explicit(&chunk->iteration,
                        ITER_PRODUCER_DIRTY | (iteration & ITER_VALUE_MASK),
                        memory_order_release);
  // 2. Make sure stores to non-atomic data are not reordered before the chunk
  // is marked dirty
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
  chunk->offset = chunk_offset;
  chunk->size = chunk_size;
  chunk->user_data = user_data;
  memcpy(producer->shbuf->header.data + chunk_offset, data, chunk_size);

  // 3. Mark the chunk as clean. Ensure non-atomic data is not reordered after
  // the chunk is marked clean.
  atomic_store_explicit(&chunk->iteration, iteration & ITER_VALUE_MASK,
                        memory_order_release);
  // 4. Update the last written index. This happens last.
  atomic_store_explicit(&producer->shbuf->descriptor->last_written_chunk_idx,
                        chunk_idx, memory_order_release);

  // bookkeeping
  producer->write_offset = (producer->write_offset + chunk_size) %
                           producer->shbuf->header.total_data_size;
  producer->last_written_chunk_idx = chunk_idx;
}
```

```
int try_read_chunk(shared_buf_consumer_t consumer,
                   uint_fast32_t expected_iteration, uint_fast32_t chunk_idx,
                   uint_fast32_t *user_data, autogrow_buf_t out_buf) {
  struct chunk_descriptor_t *chunk =
      &consumer->shbuf->descriptor->chunks_descriptors[chunk_idx];

  // 1. Check if the chunk is clean. If it is, we can read it.
  // Make sure subsequent loads of non-atomic data are not reordered before.
  uint_fast32_t chunk_iteration =
      atomic_load_explicit(&chunk->iteration, memory_order_acquire);
  if (chunk_iteration != expected_iteration) {
    return chunk_iteration;
  }
  // 2. Read the chunk size and offset.
  uint_fast32_t chunk_offset = chunk->offset;
  uint_fast32_t chunk_size = chunk->size;
  uint_fast32_t chunk_user_data = chunk->user_data;

  // 3. Make sure previous loads of non-atomic data are not reordered after.
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);

  // 4. Check if the chunk is still clean. If it is, the size and offsets are
  // consistent and can be used to read the data.
  chunk_iteration =
      atomic_load_explicit(&chunk->iteration, memory_order_acquire);
  if (chunk_iteration != expected_iteration) {
    return chunk_iteration;
  }
  // 5. Read the chunk data
  autogrow_buf_add_data(out_buf, consumer->shbuf->header.data + chunk_offset,
                        chunk_size);
  // 6. Make sure previous loads of non-atomic data are not reordered after.
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
  // 7. Check if the chunk is still clean. If it is, we're done.
  chunk_iteration =
      atomic_load_explicit(&chunk->iteration, memory_order_acquire);
  if (chunk_iteration != expected_iteration) {
    return chunk_iteration;
  }
  *user_data = chunk_user_data;
  return chunk_iteration;
}
```

First, "single total modification order" is not needed, as access will be done using acquire/release semantics from relevant threads.

Seconds, besides the "iteration" field of the chunk descriptor, which is used as a kind of lock, other fields (and the `shbuf->data`) don't need to be atomic and can be access using normal load/stores.

However, those non-atomic stores in the producer must be guaranteed to not happen before marking the chunk as dirty; and checking if the chunk is dirty in the producer must be guaranteed to happen before the non-atomic loads. This is where the `atomic_thread_fence(acquire/release)` come to action, these provide exactly those guarantees (and were missing from the question).

Note:
On strongly-ordered architectures like x86-64, no barriers are added. One thread only does stores (so that would be `StoreStore`), and the other threads only do loads (that would be `LoadLoad`). The fences make sure that the compiler doesn't reorder the non-atomic stores or loads.
On ARM, depending on the architecture level, `atomic_load/store_explicit(acquire/release)` would issue `lda/stl`. The `atomic_thread_fence(acquire/release)` should issue `dmb ishld/ishst` (although it seems that GCC is conservative and uses the `dmb ish` for both acquire/release).